# Video Problem With jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, video

On my website, I'm using a jQuery UI dialog box for some content, which includes video.  However, one big problem.  Whenever I close the dialog to reopen it (sometimes at the first run), the video downloads instead of plays.

Problems happen with all the players I tried (flowplayer, JW player, etc.).  Either the aforementioned, or it doesn't load at all.

And I tried directly from the external page and it was fine, so it has to be a jQuery UI issue.

Is there a way around this?  Anyone please?  Thanks.

```
function openDialog(url) {
    $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: '900',
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            title: 'Bonus Features',
            autoResize: true,
            beforeClose: function(){   $(this).remove();   }
        }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
            jdialog.dialog('destroy');
        }).load(url, function() {
            $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] ).bind('dialogopen', function() {
                    adjustJQueryDialogOverlay();
                });
                $(this).dialog("open");
        });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery nyromodal. it will solve all your video related problems.[click to view nyromodal demo](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)